# What's the reason of the crash of iOS app? Here are the crash logs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, app-store-connect

I've tried several devices, and no one crashes, but when I sent my build to Apple Review, they rejected it because it crashes on launch.

The first time that the app is launched, a view presents modally asking for some user preferences, and asking for allowing the legal documents. Every other time the app is launched, it displays a tab view controller.

I already Symbolicated the Crash Report

The crash logs:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

```
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18711586c __exceptionPreprocess + 220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19c12ec50 objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18701d5c8 -[NSException raise] + 15
3   Foundation                      0x18835ff58 -[NSObject+ 192344 (NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 327
4   UIKitCore                       0x18939edd8 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 95
5   UIKitCore                       0x1896dbfa4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 127
6   CoreFoundation                  0x186ff50c8 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 251
7   UIKitCore                       0x1896d7d6c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1903
8   UIKitCore                       0x1893a68c0 -[UIViewController loadView] + 591
9   UIKitCore                       0x189395f24 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 99
10  UIKitCore                       0x1893a6c7c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 199
11  UIKitCore                       0x1892e5a08 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 175
12  UIKitCore                       0x1892e5d24 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 195
13  UIKitCore                       0x1892e6bac -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 879
14  UIKitCore                       0x1892e7f88 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 167
15  UIKitCore                       0x1892c9a18 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 227
16  UIKitCore                       0x18a017ec4 -[UIView+ 17915588 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2503
17  QuartzCore                      0x18a532644 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 307
18  QuartzCore                      0x18a532b18 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1440536 (CA::Transaction*) + 523
19  QuartzCore                      0x18a54730c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1524492 (CA::Transaction*) + 143
20  QuartzCore                      0x18a48c640 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 759360 (CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 415
21  QuartzCore                      0x18a4b7b08 CA::Transaction::commit+ 936712 () + 731
22  UIKitCore                       0x189ae9f28 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 83
23  CoreFoundation                  0x18709149c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 27
24  CoreFoundation                  0x1870906e4 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 407
25  CoreFoundation                  0x18708aaa0 __CFRunLoopRun + 843
26  CoreFoundation                  0x18708a21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 599
27  GraphicsServices                0x19ec54784 GSEventRunModal + 163
28  UIKitCore                       0x189acaee8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1071
29  UIKitCore                       0x189ad075c UIApplicationMain + 167
30  Drone License Quiz              0x1048dc3ec 0x1048cc000 + 66540
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x186d4a6b0 start + 3
```

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b5065414 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d2bc0b50 pthread_kill + 272
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000190543bf4 __abort + 116
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000190543b80 __abort + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019c234cf8 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 81144 (unsigned long) + 0
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019c225e4c demangling_unexpected_handler+ 20044 () + 0
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019c12ef64 _objc_terminate+ 28516 () + 144
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019c2340e0 std::__terminate(void (*)+ 78048 ()) + 20
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019c237150 __cxa_rethrow + 148
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019c12ee1c objc_exception_rethrow + 44
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018708a308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 836
11  GraphicsServices                0x000000019ec54784 GSEventRunModal + 164
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000189acaee8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
13  UIKitCore                       0x0000000189ad075c UIApplicationMain + 168
14  Drone License Quiz              0x00000001048dc3ec 0x1048cc000 + 66540
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000186d4a6b0 start + 4
```

```
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000e00
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x3f4aa2f53b055c8b  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000066
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001050438c0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x00000001050439a0  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x00000002829d8010
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000eb1e31100  x27: 0x00000001e9f64000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016b5332d0   lr: 0x00000001d2bc0b50
    sp: 0x000000016b5332b0   pc: 0x00000001b5065414 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: Can you share the code causing this crash? Probably the first controller you’re presenting

Comment: It's a way long, summarizing: it checks a boolean from core data, if it's the first access, if it is so it calls an other view controller, else it gets other info from core data

Comment: `[UIViewController setValue:forKey:]` check the outlets. There is, at least, one dead

Comment: [UIViewController setValue:forKey:] [UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] there is probably something wrong on the outlet connection between the storyboard and the controller check them out

Comment: Solved. I used to call the `setValue:forKey:` method of NSManagedObject (Core Data), every time the app was launched.